# Keep getting a 'filedialog' error after creating executable with cx_Freeze

Tags: cx-freeze, python-3.4

I am trying to create an executable using cx_Freeze from a python script and it appears that certain portions of the tkinter module are not getting loaded into the executable file.  The script file contains the import statements:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile
from tkinter.messagebox import *
import subprocess
import time
```

Within my script I have some code that looks like this:

```
f_outfile = filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir=r'c:\Program Files (x86)\LTC\LTSpiceIV')
```

When I run this script from inside the IDLE shell, it works flawlessly.  I create an executable file with cx_Freeze using a setup.py file that looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import *

setup(name="voltage_substate_GUI",
  version="0.1",
  description="test",
  executables=[Executable("voltage_substate_GUI.pyw")],
  )
```

The executable is created without any problems, however when I run the executable I get an error in the console window that says

```
NameError: name 'filedialog is not defined'
```

However the rest of the script, which creates a GUI, appears to work just fine ---- all the buttons work as well as all the Entry() items, etc.

Any thoughts on the problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the output when you freeze it?

Comment: Try: `f_outfile = tkinter.filedialog.asksaveasfile(initialdir=r'c:\Program Files (x86)\LTC\LTSpiceIV')` This will let python know that `filedialog` is the tinter module not a variable.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, I had to import the 'filedialog' and 'messagebox' submodules explicitly in the script I was freezing.

```
import tkinter.filedialog as fdialog
import tkinter.messagebox as msgbox
import tkinter
```

While 'Label', 'Button', 'Frame', 'Entry', etc. worked fine, who knows how many others must be imported in that fashion.  Hope this helps someone.