# Freezing exe with cx-freeze and tkinter with python 3.4

Tags: python, tkinter, cx-freeze

I am having trouble getting cx-freeze to make my executable, which makes heavy use of tkinter. My setup file code is as follows:

```
import sys
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

build_exe_options = {"packages":["tkinter"]}

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

setup(
    name = "distthis",
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Report Generator",
    options = {"build_exe": build_exe_options},
    executables = [Executable("distthis.py", base=base)]   
    )
```

When I try to build this from the command line (in the same directory) I can open the program, but it won't open a filedialog. I think the problem may be with tkinter. Can anybody help?

Comment: Have you tried passing "console" or "Win32GUI" instead of None in base ?

Comment: I thought I wouldn't have to put in a bit about Win32 coz I'm only on 64bit machines - should I anyway? And what is console please?

Comment: From my understanding using "console" will show you the console when you run the script you have frozen and with "Win32GUI" it won't.

Comment: In my cx_freeze setup files, I have the `executables` inside the call to `setup()`.

Comment: Yes, you need to pass executables to setup, like in [this example](http://cx-freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html).

Comment: Ok I've amended the code - still not opening a filedialog so I think maybe tkinter is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the answer here: [Keep getting a 'filedialog' error after creating executable with cx_Freeze](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23790545/keep-getting-a-filedialog-error-after-creating-executable-with-cx-freeze)

Following the advice at the bottom of the page I changed the tkinter module imports to explicit ones and the problem was gone.

If anybody knows why this strange behaviour happens I would love to know!